# running same command for multiple links within a terminal

Tags: shell, wget

I have a file which has many links. As an example here is my file:

```
link1
link2
link3
link4
link5
link6
link7
link8
link9
link10
link11
link12
link13
link14
link15
link16
```

I want to run a particular command on a single terminal which runs 1st 4 links simultaneously. For example the command I want to run is

```
wget link1
wget link2
```

and etc.. but I want to run first 4 links simultaneously. Then if one of the link is finished downloading then the next link(which is link5) should be automatically submitted for download and so on.

I am looking for a way where I am not downloading the links one by one(uses more time), neither I have to open multiple terminals to submit multiple individual links as separate commands. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your should not have to use separate terminals. Adding a `&` to the end of a command will give you back the prompt. See shell job control. However using gnu parallel is better (automated).

Answer (score 5):

You could use GNU parallel:

```
parallel --retries 5 -j4 -a file.txt wget {}
```

This will execute 4 jobs at a time and read input from `file.txt`.  If a job fails it will be retried up to 20 times before moving on to the next job.

Comment: You are missing the part *Then if one of the link is finished downloading then the next link(which is link5) should be automatically submitted for download and so on*

Comment: @guillermochamorro: That is what `-j4` does, although it doesn't actually check that it finished _successfully_

Comment: Add `--retries 20` to `parallel` to  retry if a download fails.

Comment: Thanks @OleTange

Comment: `wget` retries 20 times by default.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Good point although there are certain conditions in which it doesn't retry:  `The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception of fatal errors like
           "connection refused" or "not found" (404), which are not retried.`

Answer (score 2):

With an `xargs` that implements the `-P` option for keeping multiple jobs running in parallel (most common implementations do):

```
xargs -I {} -P 4 wget --quiet {} <file.txt
```

Doing it *without* `xargs` or GNU `parallel`, but using `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

jobs=0
while read -r url; do
    if [ "$jobs" -ge 4 ]; then
        wait -n
        jobs=$(( jobs - 1 ))
    fi

    wget --quiet "$url" &
    jobs=$(( jobs + 1 ))
done <file.txt

wait
```

This starts `wget` background tasks as fast as possible until there has been four such jobs started.  Then it waits for any of these to end with `wait -n` before starting the next one.  The `jobs` variable holds the number of currently running `wget` jobs.

At the end, the single `wait` call will block until all jobs have finished.

It's the `wait -n` that makes this a `bash` script rather than a plain `/bin/sh` script.

Answer (score 0):

While all the answers using `parallel` and `xargs` work fine, allow me to introduce you to [GNU Wget2.](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2) It's the next version of Wget, and while it is still in alpha-mode, it is a drop-in replacement for most usages of Wget.

Wget2 supports multithreaded downloads, so you can simply give it the file and how many downloads you want in parallel, let Wget2 handle the rest for you.

Source: Am maintainer for both GNU Wget and GNU Wget2